# What is the name of the technique the example uses to pass a variable to an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

What is the name of the technique the example uses below to pass a variable to an object in javascript? And furthermore, why is it not working (**"large"** is not outputted to the console log as expected)?

```
var thumbnailBlock = new ThumbnailBlock();
thumbnailBlock.thumbnailSize = "large";


function ThumbnailBlock() {

    this.thumbnailSize;

    console.log("DEBUG");
    console.log(this.thumbnailSize);
}
```

Comment: setting a property? See [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr3Mv/)

Comment: You can't really call it a "technique" if it doesn't work …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation what is going wrong in your code from [Willem Mulder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11412636/95033):

> There is no specific name. You simply set an object property.
>
> The 'large' is not outputted because you first create an object using the ThumbnailBlock constructur function (where it logs the this.thumbnailSize) and only then set the .thumbnailSize to "large".

You could pass the size as function argument.

```
function ThumbnailBlock(size) {
    this.thumbnailSize = size;
}

var thumbnailBlock = new ThumbnailBlock("large");

console.log(thumbnailBlock.thumbnailSize);
```

Also, have a look at the [The Constructor Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript) and other nice patterns on that page. I also recommend [the chapter on OOP in the free book *Eloquent JavaScript*](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html).

Comment: Thanks @Wolfram. I'm actually reading Eloquent Javascript right now, but only on Chapter 2 so far. I've realised with this project I am working on that I know nothing about javascript so I think the beginning is a good place to start :)

Comment: Good links, Wolfram. Might I suggest for future readers that you include my answer in yours, so the question is also answered?

Comment: You're right, I did not really answer the question. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific name. You simply set an object property.

The 'large' is not outputted because you *first* create an object using the ThumbnailBlock constructur function (where it logs the this.thumbnailSize) and only *then* set the .thumbnailSize to "large".

Answer (score 1):

The proper answers are already given, I just want to point out for the record that adding dynamic property won't work if your object is [sealed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) or [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

```
function ThumbnailBlock(size) {
    Object.seal(this);
}

var thumbnailBlock = new ThumbnailBlock("large");
thumbnailBlock.thumbnailSize = 10;

console.log(thumbnailBlock.thumbnailSize); // undefined
```

In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode) you will raise an exception instead.